MonkeyPatch on ConfigParser
I have a python script that uses ConfigParser to read the config file as below:
mymodule.py:
import configparser

def read_config():
    config_ini = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config_ini.read('config.ini')

    section_list = config_ini.sections()
    dummy_key_list = []
    dummy_file_list = []

    for curr_section in section_list:
        curr_dummy_key = config_ini[curr_section].get('dummy_key', '-')
        dummy_key_list.append(curr_dummy_key)

        curr_dummy_file = config_ini[curr_section].get('dummy_file', '-')
        dummy_file_list.append(curr_dummy_file)

    return section_list, dummy_key_list, dummy_file_list

My config.ini file is as below:
[SECTION_1]
dummy_key = 'key1'
dummy_file_list = 'file1.csv'

[SECTION_2]
dummy_key = 'key2'
dummy_file_list = 'file2.tsv'

[SECTION_3]
dummy_key = 'key3'
dummy_file_list = 'file3.zip'

I want to write a testcase for this function by applying monkeypatch so that I will get the dummy result for config_ini.sections(), config_ini[curr_section].get('dummy_key', '-'), and config_ini[curr_section].get('dummy_file', '-')
I am not sure how to achieve it. Can someone explain please?
